# Velocity Dynamic Property Access

Tags: java, velocity

Is it possible to dynamically access properties by using #evaluate?  I apologize in advance for the length, but most of this is just example code to fully illustrate my issue.

I have a preferences class which looks like this:

```
public class DefaultUserPreferences implements Preferences {
    //Getters and setters left off for "brevity…"
    private Panel defaultPanel;
    private OrderByColumn mostActiveSortOrder;
    private OrderByColumn recentlyModifiedAccountsSortColumn;
}
```

Each of these types are simply a custom enum.

```
public enum OrderByColumn {
    NAME,
    LAST_ACTIVITY,
    GROUP
}

public enum Panel {
    MOST_ACTIVE,
    RECENTLY_MODIFIED;

    public String getCamelCase() {
        String[] words = StringUtils.split(this.name(), "_");
        String rval = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        if (words != null && words.length >= 1) {
            rval = StringUtils.lowerCase(words[0]);
            for(int i = 1; I < words.length; i++) {
               rval += StringUtils.capitalize(words[i].toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return rval;
    }
}
```

Below is a snippet of how I’d like to display the preferences to the users, but I can’t seem to get the getter to be called (I get the following if I evaluate it to get text: test.core.model.entities.DefaultUserPreferences@596fde80.mostActiveSortOrder)

```
#for ($panel in $Panels)
    ## The names here are correct
    #set($selectName = ${panel.CamelCase}SortColumn) 
    #set($dynamicProperty = $preferences.$selectName)
    <tr>
        <td>$panel</td>
        <td>
            <select name="$selectName">
                #for($option in $OrderByColumn)
                    <option value="$option" #if($option == #evaluate($dynamicProperty) selected="selected" #end>$option</option>
                #end
       </td>
    </tr>
#end
```

However my getter never seems to be called on the preferences.  I’ve added each of the pieces to the Context, and am not having any issues iterating over the Panels, I just can’t seem to get the syntax down to dynamically call the getters on properties.  Is this possible in 1.7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Received this from the mailing list. Basically evaluate only returns a string for display instead of returning a value.  Thus the set directive is required inside of the evaluated string.

```
#set($selectName = "${panel.CamelCase}SortColumn")
#set($dynamicProp = '#set( $selectedPreference = ' + '$preferences.' + $selectName)  + ' )')
#evaluate($dynamicProp)
```

With these lines run, I may then check the value of selectedPreference against the values I am iterating over.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at the FAQ which points to VelocityTools.

http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityFAQ